# Submit request via button javascript - Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, form-submit

Probably the title is not 100% correct. I'm writing an app in Swift and after that I filled two field of a form I want to submit them. So the button is created in this way:

```
<button class="mb3 w-100 input-reset sans-serif pointer bg-blue hover-bg-white hover-blue bg-animate ba ph3 pv2 lh-copy white b--blue b br0" data-test="login-btn">Log in</button>
```

For fill the 2 field of the form I used:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='\(firstTf.text!)'", completionHandler: nil)
```

But I'm totally lost for what about submit the request... Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT:

This is the form HTML code:

```
<form action="/login" class="measure center" data-test="login-form" method="POST"><input id="__anti-forgery-token" name="__anti-forgery-token" type="hidden" value="I/ulxtAepoMOjZvudrMhXDSqp89wIKM6hPkw7G6xHyYOqfcQIi3S/EVey1L7/CvHZI3SCbJ3Qa5rcl4j"><div class="mb3"><label class="db f6 mb2 b">Email</label><input class="mb1 pv2 lh-copy ph3 input-reset sans-serif black-80 ba bg-transparent w-100 b--black-20" name="email" type="email"><div class="f6 black-50 dn">Don't worry, we hate spam as much as you do</div></div><div class="mb3"><label class="db f6 mb2 b">Password</label><input class="pv2 lh-copy ph3 input-reset sans-serif ba bg-transparent w-100 b--black-20" name="password" type="password"></div><div class="mv3 lh-title"></div><div><button class="mb3 w-100 input-reset sans-serif pointer bg-blue hover-bg-white hover-blue bg-animate ba ph3 pv2 lh-copy white b--blue b br0" data-test="login-btn">Log in</button></div><div class="f6 black-50 tc lh-copy"><div><a class="link blue hover-dark-blue ml1 dib" data-test="forgot-password" href="/reset-password">Forgot your password?</a></div></div></form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the element and then call `.submit()` on it.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('FORM').submit()", completionHandler: nil)
```

something like this might do the job for you.

Since the form don't have an id, I assume that you don't have control over the website that you are showing, so adding an id is not an option. Because i don't have the whole page I would like to have an id to get from. You can navigate the DOM and get a child of the form that has an id and then ask for the parent.

```
document.getElementById('__anti-forgery-token').parentNode.submit()
```

This should invoke a submit of the form.

Comment: I will try and I’ll let you know. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: Sorry, cause of the Time Zone difference I didn't have the time to test... Unfortunately it's not working because there is no ID "FORM" in any HTML lines

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.Instead of use "submit()" on TagName, I used "click()" as follow:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()", completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: That is not true, you can use `submit()` on `getElementsByTagName` its just a DOM selector, it does not determine the methods you can use on it.

Comment: Perhaps your code is wrong. It could be a subject for a new question. But what you are writing is not true.

Comment: Not at all... As you can see is the same as the previous, with the only difference that is not submit() but click()...

Comment: But button, don't have a submit() method a form has. Perhaps thats your problem.

Comment: Read my updated question, you will find the HTML form there... I grabbed it from a website, I haven't wrote by my own and there is no ID on form...

Comment: Read my updated answer, `getElementById` is just a method to get a node from the DOM. `getElementsByTagName` is also just a selector for the DOM, it does not influence the methods a node has. I use getElementsById because the ID is unique and i don't know your whole DOM on the page you are looking, and I'm sure the parent is form.

Comment: Yes I seen it! Thanks